# Code for Chartjs Typescript definition file

Tags: typescript, chart.js

I am using Chartjs in a small typescript project.  I want to put the necessary code in a definition file so Typescipt will allow this line

[image]

I have made no progress.  The chartjs file in Definitely Typed has nothing in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this appears to be working for the moment.

```
declare module cjs {
interface IChart {
    new (context:any):ChartObject;
}
interface ChartObject {
    Line(data:any, options?:any): void;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the `chartjs` folder does not contain *this* chartjs definition. I've reported (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/2830) and will delete it shortly.